# android : AES encryption / decryption using openSSL

Tags: android, openssl, aes

I want to encrypt / decrypt files ( of reasonable size ). I have my code working corrects using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding . The problem is that it takes really long time to encrypt big files. SO now I am planning to use openSSL.

Is there a link that explains how to use openssl from a java app? How can I integrate it to my java app?

Thanks a lot for any links / points in this regard.
Thanks for your help and time

My code using BC:

```
public class BouncyCastleProvider_AES_CBC {
    public Cipher encryptcipher, decryptCipher;
    String TAG = "DataEncryptDecrypt";
    private static final String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";

     // The default block size
    public static int blockSize = 16;


    // Buffer used to transport the bytes from one stream to another
    byte[] buf = new byte[blockSize];       //input buffer
    byte[] obuf = new byte[512];            //output buffer

    // The key
    byte[] key = null;
    // The initialization vector needed by the CBC mode
    byte[] IV = null;

    public BouncyCastleProvider_AES_CBC(String passwd){
        //for a 192 key you must install the unrestricted policy files
        //  from the JCE/JDK downloads page
        key =passwd.getBytes();
        key = "SECRETSECRET_1SE".getBytes();
        Log.i( "SECRETSECRET_1SECRET_2", "length"+ key.length);
        //default IV value initialized with 0
        IV = new byte[blockSize];
        InitCiphers();

    }

    public BouncyCastleProvider_AES_CBC(String pass, byte[] iv){
        //get the key and the IV

        IV = new byte[blockSize];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0 , IV, 0, iv.length);
    }
    public BouncyCastleProvider_AES_CBC(byte[] pass, byte[]iv){
        //get the key and the IV
        key = new byte[pass.length];
        System.arraycopy(pass, 0 , key, 0, pass.length);
        IV = new byte[blockSize];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0 , IV, 0, iv.length);
    }

    public void InitCiphers()
            {
        try {
       //1. create the cipher using Bouncy Castle Provider
       encryptcipher =
               Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
       //2. create the key
       SecretKey keyValue = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
       //3. create the IV
       AlgorithmParameterSpec IVspec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
       //4. init the cipher
       encryptcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
       encryptcipher.getOutputSize(100);

       //1 create the cipher
       decryptCipher =
               Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
       //2. the key is already created
       //3. the IV is already created
       //4. init the cipher
       decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public String encryptData(String inputFileName) {
        String outFilename = null;
        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        try {

            // step 3 - not needed, as we have all the blocks on hand

            // step 4 - call doFinal()

             outFilename = ".".concat(CommonUtils.getHash(inputFile.getName()));
            InputStream fis;
            OutputStream fos;
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));

            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    inputFile.getParent() + "/" + outFilename));
            Log.i(TAG, "Output path:" + inputFile.getParent() + "/" + outFilename);
            int bufferLength = (inputFile.length()>10000000?10000000:1000);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
            int noBytes = 0;
            byte[] cipherBlock = new byte[encryptcipher
                    .getOutputSize(buffer.length)];
            int cipherBytes;
            while ((noBytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                cipherBytes = encryptcipher.update(buffer, 0, noBytes,
                        cipherBlock);
                fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            }
            // always call doFinal
            cipherBytes = encryptcipher.doFinal(cipherBlock, 0);
            fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);

            // close the files
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.i("encrpty", "done");
            inputFile.delete();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputFile.getParent() + "/" + outFilename;
    }

    public void decryptData(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) {
        InputStream fis;
        OutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    inputFileName));
            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    outputFileName));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize*100];
            int noBytes = 0;
            byte[] cipherBlock = new byte[decryptCipher
                    .getOutputSize(buffer.length)];
            int cipherBytes;
            while ((noBytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                cipherBytes = decryptCipher.update(buffer, 0, noBytes,
                        cipherBlock);
                fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            }
            // allways call doFinal
            cipherBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(cipherBlock, 0);
            fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);

            // close the files
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            new File(inputFileName).delete();

            Log.i("decrypt", "done");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public byte[] generateSalt()  {
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];

        try {
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return salt;

    }



}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Bouncycastle](http://bouncycastle.org/) crypto library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Guardian Project has build files for Android. Once you build it, you need write a simple JNI wrapper that does the encryption/decryption using OpenSSL APIs (EVP, etc), then call this from your app. You need to include he openssl and your JNI wrapper in the app and load them on startup using `System.loadLibrary()`.

https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android

Additionally:

- don't derive a password from a string directly, use a proper derivation algorithm.
- don't use a fixed IV, especially all zeros

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will take care of the two points mentioned, i was trying to get the algorithm ready and then change those parts. Regarding JNI wrapper do you know any sample projects. I have never worked with NDK or wrote JNI wrappers. Any link would be really helpful . Also can you please confirm this point that we can achiieve faster performance for big files ONLY using native code like openSSL ? DO you have any other suggestion. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: Well, the NDK is just a way to compile native (C/C++) code, so if you are comfortable with C, you shouldn't have nay problems. As for JNI, you only need two or three methods (initialize, encrypt, decrypt), so it should be a very thin wrapper. As for the actual encryption part, most OpenSSL tutorials should teach you how to do this. I can't guarantee that it will be much, much faster :) You'll have to experiment and benchmark, possibly on different devices. Links: JNI Book (with sample code): http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/ NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html